# Angular 4 / Angular Material 2 - Sidenav is not defined. The component declaration does not contain such a member

Tags: javascript, angular, flexbox, angular-material

I have created a new project using Angular 4 and Material design 2.

I have added a sidenav and a toolbar.

It all worked well when all the html was on app.comentent.html but I then created a new component to add the toolbar code and I started getting the error:

Here is the code:

**app-topnav component:**

```
<md-toolbar color="primary">

  <button md-icon-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()">
    <md-icon class="md-24 material-icons">menu</md-icon>
  </button>

  <span class="topbar-spacer"></span>

  <button md-icon-button class="topbar-button-right">
    <md-icon class="md-24 material-icons">notifications</md-icon>
  </button>

  <button md-icon-button class="topbar-button-right">
    <md-icon class="md-24 material-icons">more_vert</md-icon>
  </button>

</md-toolbar>
```

**app.component:**

```
<md-sidenav-container>
    <md-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" class="app-sidenav">
      <md-nav-list>
        <div class="app-user-photo">
          <img class="round user" src="../assets/image.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <md-list>
          <md-list-item><i class="material-icons">Home</i><span>Home</span></md-list-item>
        </md-list>
      </md-nav-list>
    </md-sidenav>
    <app-topnav></app-topnav>
    <div class="app-content">
      Content area<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    </div>
</md-sidenav-container>**
```

How can I fix this so that the sidenav toogle works again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue as yours at one point. I solved this by not separating  `md-toolbar` to `md-sidenav-container`. A lot of snippets in github doesnt separate sidenav and toolbar often the two are in the same view. I prefer not to separate the two.

```
<md-sidenav-container>
  <md-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" class="app-sidenav">
    <md-nav-list>
      <div class="app-user-photo">
        <img class="round user" src="../assets/image.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <md-list>
        <md-list-item><i class="material-icons">Home</i><span>Home</span></md-list-item>
      </md-list>
    </md-nav-list>
  </md-sidenav>

  <md-toolbar color="primary">

    <button md-icon-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()">
      <md-icon class="md-24 material-icons">menu</md-icon>
    </button>

    <span class="topbar-spacer"></span>

    <button md-icon-button class="topbar-button-right">
      <md-icon class="md-24 material-icons">notifications</md-icon>
    </button>

    <button md-icon-button class="topbar-button-right">
      <md-icon class="md-24 material-icons">more_vert</md-icon>
    </button>

  </md-toolbar>

  <div class="app-content">
    Content area<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  </div>
</md-sidenav-container>
```